# Is PCV13 effective if the suspension is not shaken prior to administration?

Tags: immune-system, vaccination

PCV13, like other vaccines which are suspensions, should be shaken vigorously to obtain a homogenous, white suspension in the vaccine container immediately prior to use.

If this is not done and the vaccine is administered as a clear liquid, will it still evoke an adequate immune response in the patient?

Edit: I am not questioning the necessity of 'shaking well before use' if it is explicitly mentioned on the label. What I want to know is whether the vaccine is rendered ineffective if this instruction is neglected. Would it necessitate re-immunization?

I ask this because I recently witnessed a health professional fail to shake the PCV13 prefilled syringe before use. When I brought this to her attention, she said that she was not aware of this and hadn't been doing it for any of the suspension/adjuvant vaccines. I wonder if there might be other health professionals who are unaware of this requirement. If so, how protected are the recipients of this important vaccine? Should they be re-immunized?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Specifically, have you wondered why the instructions would say to do so if it wasn't necessary?

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you for the pointers. Please see the edit. I hope my question makes more sense now. Google did not yield any satisfactory answers. All I found was a list of vaccines which need to be shaken before use.

Comment: Ah, it was a pre-filled syringe. I think that's going to make a big difference than if she had failed to shake a multi-dose vial.

Comment: Frankly I doubt this has been tested (besides perhaps in an analytical manufacturing context to set instructions). Trials are expensive. Unless a particular misuse is common enough to attract academic interest, people aren't typically funding trials for failure to adhere to basic instructions.